# Custom RequiredIf attribute not working in client-side Blazor

Tags: blazor

I have blazor page like

```
<EditForm Model="@MyModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
  <DataAnnotationsValidator />
  ...
  <MyComponent DataModel="@MyModel.Transaction" />
</EditForm>
@code {
    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
    }
}
```

`MyComponent.razor`

```
...
<InputText @bind-Value="@Model.InputValue" disabled="@Model.TextboxDisabled" />


@code {
   [Parameter]
   public MyModel DataModel { get; set; }
}
```

and

MyModel.cs

```
[RequiredIf(nameof(TextBoxEnabled), true)]
public string InputValue { get; set; }

public bool TextBoxEnabled { get; set; }

public bool TextBoxDisabled => !TextBoxEnabled;
```

RequiredIfAttribute.cs

```
public sealed class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string propertyName;
    private readonly object? isValue;
    private readonly bool inverse;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequiredIfAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the depending property.</param>
    /// <param name="isValue">Required value. If <see cref="propertyName"/> is <see cref="isValue"/> then the property is not required.</param>
    /// <param name="inverse">If set to true, the value is not required when <see cref="propertyName"/> is
    /// not <see cref="isValue"/>.</param>
    public RequiredIfAttribute(string propertyName, object? isValue, bool inverse = false)
    {
      this.propertyName = propertyName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));
      this.isValue = isValue;
      this.inverse = inverse;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
      var inverseString = !inverse ? string.Empty : "not ";
      var errorMessage = $"Property '{name}' is required when '{propertyName}' is {inverseString}'{isValue}'";
      return ErrorMessage ?? errorMessage;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
      var isRequired = IsRequired(validationContext, propertyName, isValue, inverse);
      if (!isRequired)
      {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
      }

      var validationResult = value == null
          ? new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName))
          : ValidationResult.Success;
      return validationResult;
    }

    private static bool IsRequired(
        ValidationContext? validationContext,
        string propertyName,
        object? requiredValue,
        bool invert)
    {
      ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(validationContext);
      ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(propertyName);

      var owningType = validationContext.ObjectType;
      var property = owningType.GetProperty(propertyName);

      if (property == null)
      {
        throw new NotSupportedException($"Can't find {propertyName} on searched type: {owningType.Name}");
      }

      var requiredIfTypeActualValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

      if (requiredIfTypeActualValue == null && requiredValue != null)
      {
        return false;
      }

      if (!invert)
      {
        return requiredIfTypeActualValue == null || requiredIfTypeActualValue.Equals(requiredValue);
      }

      return requiredIfTypeActualValue == null || !requiredIfTypeActualValue.Equals(requiredValue);
    }
}
```

When textbox become enabled, and press Submit, the `HandleValidSubmit` is executed and I expected to fail (means to not execute that method) because RequiredIf is based on that flag `TextBoxEnabled` and textbox is empty.

There's another approach to make `RequiredIf` workable on client-side validation ?

Comment: This was game changing for me when it comes to Blazor and validation. Things like above are so simple once you get the infrastructure in. https://chrissainty.com/using-fluentvalidation-for-forms-validation-in-razor-components/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where or how you're toggling `TextBoxEnabled`, but that is probably where your problem lies.  Here's a working version of your code with the on/off in the component.

**MyComponent.razor**

```
<div class="mb-3 form-check">
    <InputCheckbox class="form-check-input" @bind-Value=Model.TextBoxEnabled />
    <label class="form-check-label">I want to enter something</label>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value=Model.InputValue disabled="@Model.TextBoxDisabled" />
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MyModel Model { get; set; } = new MyModel();
}
```

And the test page:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text

<EditForm Model=@Model OnValidSubmit=@HandleValidSubmit OnInvalidSubmit=@HandleInValidSubmit>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <MyComponent Model=@Model />
    <div class="p-2 text-end">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

    <div class="m-4 p-2">
       <strong>Submit Messages</strong>:<pre>@message.ToString()</pre> 
    </div>

@code {
    private StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    public MyModel Model = new MyModel();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        message.AppendLine($"Valid Submit at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }

    private void HandleInValidSubmit()
    {
        message.AppendLine($"Invalid Submit at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }
}
```

Here's the results:

[image]